# Boltforms multiple (same) forms on 1 page sent twice

Tags: bolt-cms

When I have multiple forms on one page with boltforms the submission sent twice. It are two the same forms one in a modal and one in the footer. How fix this? And if I made two different forms woulds that resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The form submission is handled by the boltforms system based on the name of the form - if you have two forms on the same page both forms will be triggered, and if the name of those forms is the same, both forms will continue with the submission.

If you make two forms that have different names, only one of the forms will continue, so that would fix your problem.